# C# worker thread with event driven work and no shut down

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Here's what I woulld like to do:

1. Create a worker thread in my main thread (which controls the UI).
2. The worker thread keeps running until shut down by the main thread (which only happens when the entire application is shut down).
3. The main thread listens for keyup, but sends an event to the worker thread to process the keyup asynchronously (to avoid blocking the UI).
4. The worker thread updates the UI when the keyup has been handled.

So far I've just been creating a new thread every time there is a keyup, but it seems there is just too much overhead this way.

As far as I can tell, I should use the BackgroundWorker class, but the examples I've seen seems to start a background worker, continue with non-blocked UI in the main thread and update UI from the BackgroundWorker when it's finished - i.e. exactly the same as I'm already doing.

How to make it so the worker thread keeps running and sleep when there is no work to be done?

Comment: Try using a blocking queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Zaches answer is completely valid (and an approach I used for some time) I've stumbled upon what I think is a more elegant solution using `Dispatcher`:

Create the worker thread:

```
Dispatcher _workerDispatcher;
Thread _workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    _workerDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher; // Required to create the dispatcher
    Dispatcher.Run(); // Keeps thread alive and creates a queue for work
});
_workerThread.Start();
```

Put work into the worker thread (from main thread or another thread):

```
// Synchronous work
_workerDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    // Do stuff
});

// Asynchronous work (makes most sense for background work)
_workerDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    // Do stuff
});
```

Shut down the worker thread:

```
_workerDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
_workerThread.Join(); // Wait for thread to shut down
```

I'm using `new Thread()` because I need to set apartment state, but you can also use tasks created using `Task.Run()` and `Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

I'm not 100% certain that it's necessary to call `thread.Join()`, but I'd rather be certain that the thread has been shut down. If you're using a `Task` call `task.Wait()` instead.

Another way to get the `Dispatcher` is to call `Dispatcher.FromThread(thread)`, but it's important to note that a `Dispatcher` is **NOT** created until `CurrentDispatcher` has been used (even if you don't use the reference later).

A downside of this approach is that it can't be used to have multiple threads pick items out of a queue and do work - for that you will have to use the producer/consumer approached described in Zaches answer. The dispatcher approach allows you to queue up work in a *specific* thead.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the [Task Parallel Library](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fdd460717.aspx&ei=KTZNUvGvKImJ4gSj_YDICw&usg=AFQjCNGjTfP3C9wE1gKSbCEzZlCOZrAYkA&bvm=bv.53537100,d.bGE)?

Create a new task whenever you detect the KeyUp event, and let TPL worry about creating new threads. Since it uses the thread pool, a new thread will not be created every time an event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is called the Producer/Consumer problem. And you can solve it easily using any of the ConcurrentCollections available.

Try something like this:

```
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
var consume = true;

var producer = Task.Run(() => 
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) 
    {
       queue.Enqueue(input);
       input = Console.ReadLine();         
    }
});

var consumer = Task.Run(() => 
{
    while(consume) //So we can stop the consumer
    {
        while(!queue.IsEmpty) //So we empty the queue before stopping
        {
            stringres;
            if(queue.TryDequeue(out res)) Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
});

await producer;
consume = false;
await consumer;
```

Try using the Task Pattern Library instead of manually starting up threads. It is your friend.

Comment: Don't fire ThreadPool thread for long running  task. use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` to create a dedicated thread for you